# Alert on New List Entries

Tags: alert

I have a list where I need to keep the form responses private to only the user who submitted. I changed the Advanced Setting on the list to allow the user to only read, edit and create items that belonged to them. Problem solved? Not so quickly...

I need this list to trigger an alert email when a new item is created, but SP is telling me that Alerts are not available when it is set for restrictive viewing. Does anyone know of a work around? or another option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could always make a simple workflow to send an email to the submitter.

On create/or change

Send an email to User who created( or who ever it needs to be sent to)

End the workflow

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options

1. Write a workflow to send mail(recommended option) On item Created...
2. Write a event receiver on event ItemCreated and send mail to intended recipient.